# My question was closed but I think it was on-topic (Perhaps because there is no IT asset being protected?)

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This is my question: [Can the IBAN of the initiator of a SEPA direct debit be faked?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/272544/can-the-iban-of-the-initiator-of-a-sepa-direct-debit-be-faked).

I don't really mind it getting closed I just want to understand why it was closed. So I won't do the same mistake in the future.

I've read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and it says:

> IT Security Stack Exchange is for Information Security professionals to discuss protecting assets from threats and vulnerabilities.

In my case the asset is the money on my bank account (which is a database entry; as you see the question is about IT). The threat is a scammer using my IBAN in an online shop. The vulnerability is that IBANs in SEPA direct debits can perhaps be faked.

I suppose that by definition only information assets are meant (on the SE help site) and that could be the reason why my question was closed. And database entries seem not to be evaluated as IT assets (Doesn't make sense?). But I am not sure.

Also I found a similar question which was not closed:

[Can someone steal money from my bank account if they know my IBAN and personal details?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/can-someone-steal-money-from-my-bank-account-if-they-know-my-iban-and-personal-d). In this question the asset being protected is also money. So why was that question not closed while my was?

My question is definitely about information technology. Direct debits are just entries in databases. Bank account statements are log files. Maybe someone can explain why it was closed.

Answer (score 0):

> "which is a database entry; as you see the question is about IT"

That's one of the biggest stretches of logic I've seen here.

The other IBAN question you linked? That was from 2011, and was one of the first questions on the site and exists for historical reasons. We've figured out that we can't tackle things that are essentially questions about how banking systems work.

Which is exactly what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a question that is about IT does not make it on topic here. Writing a question about security does not make it on topic here. You should thoroughly read our [about] and [ask] pages to get a better feel for what is on topic.

Finding one old question that appears similar is also not a good way to see if a question is on topic - if there were many, highly upvoted questions on that topic, that would be a much better indicator.